# Why is there only one finite field for a prime-power order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I know that finite fields only exist for prime-power order. Why is there only one finite field for a prime-power order?

Comment: Do you know of splitting fields?

Comment: I don't know about splitting fields.

Comment: Any textbook that contains the statement (that finite fields of a given size are unique up to isomorphism) should also contain a proof of that statement.